# Geonode installation on Ubuntu fails

Tags: installation, ubuntu, geonode

attention: This might be more a question for "askubuntu.stackexchange" but it is GIS-related
Geonode 2.0 is available for Ubuntu 12.04 but not for Ubuntu 14.04. According to the docs it should be sufficient to make an

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geonode/release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install geonode
```

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 12.04 with a default LAMP configuration and it already fails on the first line:

```
Depends: python-pycurl but is not installable
```

The first line works on Ubuntu 14.04 but geonode will not be installable on 14.04. I am somewhere stucked. Is there a Geonode release available for 14.04?

Comment: I have the same problem, I will try to use a different package https://launchpad.net/~geonode. The osgeo PPA packege seem to be built for Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I've questioned it here as well, but got no good response so far: http://askubuntu.com/questions/523812/fresh-install-python-software-properties-unmet-dependencies?noredirect=1#comment713620_523812

Answer (score 2):

It seems that a stable version of geonode 2.x branch is not still released for Ubuntu 14.04. [The suggestion of the developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/geonode-users/_ys8unjM0Pw) is install the testing 2.4 version from the ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geonode/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install geonode

geonode createsuperuser
sudo geonode-updateip 127.0.0.1
```

You can also try to install it by hand as [is shown in this post](http://dotsconnect.us/articles/geonode-with-vagrant-virtualbox/), where is installed in virtual machine of ubuntu 14.04 with vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that ppa:geonode/testing works on Ubuntu 14.04; then you have to add at the end of the file /etc/geonode/local_settings.py (otherwise you'll have this error 403 forbidden DEBUG is set to False but the host of the path provided to the proxy service is not in the PROXY_ALLOWED_HOSTS setting) this line:

`PROXY_ALLOWED_HOSTS = ('127.0.0.1',)`

and then restart apache `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.